# Правильный запрос SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

```
$row = 'SELECT
          *
        FROM
          datatable
        WHERE
          sh="QWERTY' .  mysql_real_escape_string($sh) . '"';
```

Что дописать в запрос , чтобы он вывел строку с максимальным значением параметра `age`.

Ну т.е строк с параметром `sh` много, нужно вывести с максимальным `age`.

Что дописать?

Comment: `order by age desc limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = 'SELECT
          id,sh,MAX(age)
        FROM
          datatable
        WHERE
          sh="QWERTY' .  mysql_real_escape_string($sh) . '"';
```